What's the difference between TBitmapSurface and TBitmap in Delphi?
I normally use TBitmap for everything, but I recently saw TBitmapSurface and thought it might be faster. I'm new to Delphi and haven't used TBitmapSurface yet. I've only ever used TBitmap.
What are the differences, and why would someone use one over the other?

TBitmap ist VCL and specific to Windows, while TBitmapSurface is FMX.

@AndreRuebel But I'm using TBitmap in FMX for Android. It is not specific to Windows. Don't you mean the image file format .BMP instead, which is Windows specific AFAIK?
